# LoginListener doesn't work : undefined method

Tags: symfony, authentication, event-listener

I want to recover the date of the last time a user logged in my Symfony 5 website, I created a LoginListener and did the right settings (So-think-I ?) to make it work but in the class Login Listener :

```
namespace App\Event;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{
    private $em;
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // Get the User entity.
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        
        // Update your field here.
        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
        
        // Persist the data to database.
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

The `setLastLogin(new \DateTime())` is described as an undefined method. Yet this method is in the entity User.php and it is properly called in the loginlistener. And the `"use App\Entity\User` :

```
/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function setLastLogin(\DateTime $time = null)
  {
    $this->lastLogin = $time;

    return $this;
  }

/**
  * Gets the last login time.
  *
  * @return \DateTime|null
  */
  public function getLastLogin()
  {
    return $this->lastLogin;
  }

  /**
  * @var \DateTime $lastLogin
  *
  * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
  */
  private $lastLogin;
```

And when I try to make a `exit(var_dump($user)`, nothing appears. Here is my services.yaml :

```
App\EventListener\LoginListener:
    - tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login', entity: 'App\Entity\User' }
```

Can someone help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you configure a User Provider? See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#security-entity-user-provider

Comment: The variable $user is probably not an instance of User. What do you see if you add dump($user) before $user->setLastLogin(,,,)?

Comment: Hey, I just did it and the dump does not make anything appear or I don't know where to see it.

Comment: As far as your IDE is concerned, `getAuthenticationToken()->getUser()` returns a UserInterface.  Your IDE has no idea that your particular user class is being returned.  Use the var annotation to tell your IDE that $user is an instance of App\Enitity\User.

Comment: Okay, how do I do that ? Sorry I am a begginer in Symfony ^^'

Comment: This is not Symfony related. Just add `/** @var App\Entity\User $user */` above your `$user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();` Or check that your `$user` is indeed a `User` (`if ($user instanceof App\Entity\User) { /* ... */ }`)

Comment: As for your dump, a few comments up, you can see them in the `Debug` section of the profiler.